# A TM that doesn't decide Σ*, and a TM that doesn't decide the empty set?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, undecidability, semi-decidability

I was wondering if it was possible to create a TM that semi-decides (but doesn't decide) either of the following two languages:

1. $\emptyset$
2. $\Sigma^{*}$

I assume for 2, a one-state TM that just automatically accepts would be fine? I don't think it's possible for any input not to halt, or be rejected, so technically the TM would just semi-decide?

However, for 1, I'm not 100% sure what that TM would look like. Would I just have to figure out a way to have *at least one* input (or, more simply, all inputs), not halt, since none could possibly accept?

Edit: I know such TMs **must** exist, I'm more so confused as to what they *look* like.

Comment: Both of your languages are decidable, and so semi-decidable.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm wondering is how would one go about building a TM that _only_ semi-decides the language, and does not decide. For other languages it can be easy (just ignore the rejecting state, or keep on reading forever). But for something like the universe, how could it _not_ be decidable and _only_ semi-decidable?

Comment: For the empty language, take a Turing machine that enters an infinite loop (regardless of the input). For the complete language, take a Turing machine which immediately halts.

Comment: @yuval, should be an answer not a comment

Comment: I don't think Yuval's answer is correct. A TM that immediately halts for the complete language would either be incorrect (if it doesn't accept, than it doesn't actually (semi)decide the language), or deciding (if it immediately accepts, then it decides, and doesn't semi-decide)

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what *decide* and *semi-decide* mean for you.